# Importing data from Excel with a Word macro

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to import data from an Excel file into Word.

The trick would be part of a Word VBA macro, so I would have to perform in from Word, not Excel.

I need the macro in Word to open excel, copy the data for an excel cell, close excel and paste the data in a cell in word.

Any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: Well, not that hard. I suggest to type in google "open excel in word vba" and it will come up with many tips. You just have to include Excel in the vba references of your word document and create an "Excel.Application" as a variable. With that variable, you can use all methods you know from excel-vba. Open a workbook, copy some of it contents, paste it to your word document and close workbook and excel application afterwards.

Comment: Is the fact that I'm working on a Mac the reason why this might not be working the way everyone suggests? Thx

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
Sub OpenExcelFile()

    Dim Excel As Excel.Application
    Dim WB As Workbook

    Set Excel = New Excel.Application
    Set WB = Excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\filepath.xls")
    Excel.Visible = True
    Set WB = Excel.Workbooks.Open(sPath)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have tried this before and I always get the following error (I'll try to translate well from Spanish...): "the type defined by the user has not been defined". I'm not sure if the fact that I'm running the macro on a Mac might be the problem... Would this make sense?

Comment: Hmmm possibly. Theres an article here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/894030